# Using slice to remove "The" from meta tag description

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, slice, meta-tags

I have a meta tag description where I want to get the grant name.  However many of the grant names start with The like "The Smithsonian Grant".  I want my meta tag to say "Apply online to the Smithsonian Grant" not "the The Smithsonian Grant". How would I go about removing the first word of the grant name if it is "The"?

I tried this:

```
<% meta_description "Apply online to the #{@grant.name.slice("The")} on Instrumentl" %>
```

but the result is

```
<meta name="description" content="Apply online to the The on Instrumentl" />
```

That wasn't how I was expecting slice to work.  I also tried .slice!, .reduce, and .except in place of .slice but none of those worked.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `gsub` which will replace any part of a matched string with replacement string. If the replacement string is empty, it'll just remove the matched string entirely:

```
>> "The Smithsonian Grant".gsub(/^the */i, "")
=> "Smithsonian Grant"

>> "Winnie the pooh".gsub(/^the */i, "")
=> "Winnie the pooh"
```